Is it possible to create AWS Elasticache Redis cluster in highly available configuration with durable data
I need AWS Elasticache Redis cluster with durable data. Specifically all data written to Redis should be safe in case of one node failure.
For those who answer "You do not need it, Redis is for transient data": Well, I need to store some realtime counters. They are short term, fast (500 ops/sec) and very-very expensive to restore.
I want to be sure that in case of one node failure data will not be lost.
Default Elasticache Redis as far as I understand will loose "small portion of data", which is not acceptable.
I know such setup is possible in on prem config.
UPD: Answering my own question. AWS MemoryDB. Same Redis, a bit more expensive, but with data durability SLA

Check ElastiCache Redis Replication group (HA) documentation  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Replication.html
